# Monogame - how to make a smooth color transition with Color.Lerp()?

Tags: monogame, color

I would like to know how to dynamically change a color. My code:

```
Color myColor;
Color startColor = new Color(255, 255, 255);
Color finalColor = new Color(231, 214, 90);
myColor = Color.Lerp(startColor, finalColor, 0.5f);

spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, Vector2.Zero, myColor);
```

But the color does not change, in fact I get something similar to the `finalColor`, that's perhaps because I need to decrement the `RGB` values of `startColor` and check if they match `finalColor`? Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [Color.Lerp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.color.lerp(v=xnagamestudio.31).aspx) documentation you'll notice that the third parameter is the `amount`.

```
public static Color Lerp(Color value1, Color value2, float amount)
```

> amount - A value between 0 and 1.0 indicating the weight of value2.

What this means is that to get the color to change you'll need to change the `amount` over time between values of 0.0 and 1.0. To do this, create a member variable in your class and change it in the `Update` method.

```
 private float _colorAmount = 0.0f;

 protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
 {
     var deltaSeconds = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

     _colorAmount += deltaTime;

     if(_colorAmount > 1.0f)
         _colorAmount = 0.0f;

     // rest of update method...
 }

 protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
 {  
     // start of draw method..

     var startColor = new Color(255, 255, 255);
     var finalColor = new Color(231, 214, 90);
     var myColor = Color.Lerp(startColor, finalColor, _colorAmount);

     spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, Vector2.Zero, myColor);

    // rest of draw method...
}
```

Obviously the actual logic you use will differ from the example here, but this should give you enough to get started.

Comment: I can't see why this isn't directly useable but I'd wrap `_colorAmount`, rather than truncate it. Consider adding, as an example, running `_colorAmount` through a trig function to get a nice repeating back and forth between -1:1, scaled to 0:1.

Comment: Maybe show how actually uncomplicated it is too: `Color Lerp(Color c0, Color c1, float t) { return (1-t)*c0 + t*c1; }`

Comment: @Jon I realize my example won't produce the nicest animation but I think it's better to keep the example as simple as possible without complicating it with extra information. There's loads of [different ways](http://sol.gfxile.net/interpolation/) to interpolate between 0 and 1 once you understand the basics.

Comment: @craftworkgames Oh now I see. I read those docs but I hadn't drank my coffee yet so I couldn't figure it out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. Animation code is fun to write.

Answer (score 1):

I made this general class to help with any kinda lerping transitions. Thought maybe someone could use it. `Memory.gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds` is a public static variable that my project uses to track the game time you might need to change that for your project.

```
    public class Slide<T>
    {
        #region Fields

        private double _currentMS;
        private T _end;
        private Func<T, T, float, T> _function;
        private T _start;
        private double _totalMS;

        #endregion Fields

        #region Constructors

        public Slide(T start, T end, double totalMS, Func<T, T, float, T> function)
        {
            _start = start;
            _end = end;
            _totalMS = totalMS;
            _function = function;
        }

        #endregion Constructors

        #region Properties

        public double CurrentMS => _currentMS;
        public bool Done => _currentMS >= _totalMS;

        public T End { get => _end; set => _end = value; }
        public Func<T, T, float, T> Function { get => _function; set => _function = value; }
        public T Start { get => _start; set => _start = value; }
        public double TotalMS { get => _totalMS; set => _totalMS = value; }

        #endregion Properties

        #region Methods

        public void Restart() => _currentMS = 0d;

        public void Reverse()
        {
            T tmp = _start; _start = _end; _end = tmp;
        }

        public float UpdatePercent()
        {
            if (!Done)
            {
                _currentMS += Memory.gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
                return (float)(Done ? 1f : _currentMS / _totalMS);
            }
            else
                return 1f;
        }

        public T Update()
        {
            float percent;
            if (_function!=null && (percent = UpdatePercent())!=1f)
                return _function(_start, _end, percent);
            return _end;
        }

        #endregion Methods
    }
```

For this question the you can use.

```
Slide<Color> ColorSlider = new Slide<Color>(new Color(255, 255, 255),
                               new Color(231, 214, 90), 2000d, Color.Lerp);
Color cval = ColorSlider.Update();
```